How to Log Unsubscribe Events for Mobile Push Notifications When Users Opt Out
I'm working on mobile push notifications, and I'm looking for a feature similar to the "log unsub event" that exists for email. Specifically, I want to ensure that if a user opts out of receiving mobile push notifications via a preference center, they are also marked as unsubscribed in the "All Contacts" list for mobile push.
Is there an existing function or best practice for handling this scenario?

There is an unofficial way to do it that you can update the unsupported _PushAddress data view. You can check the fields of that data view in this SE answer.
Opt-out:
%%[
  set @SubscriberID = '12345'
  UpdateData('_PushAddress', 1, '_ContactID', @SubscriberID, '_OptOutStatusID', 1, '_OptInStatusID', 0)
]%%

Opt-in:
%%[
  set @SubscriberID = '12345'

  UpdateData('_PushAddress', 1, '_ContactID', @SubscriberID, '_OptOutStatusID', 0, '_OptInStatusID', 2)
]%%

However, the logic that you want to opt out/opt in Mobile Push from the preference center may not work well based on the fact that not all subscribers from the email channel are existing in the Push channel. Not mention that you have to find a way to link an attribute value in this data view (E.g. SubscriberID since this data view doesn't have the contact key/subscriber key attribute) to your preference center so it can execute the update action.
I would recommend that you let your subscribers opt-in/opt-out organically through their mobile device.
Reference: SFMC mobile push opt-out

If a contact deletes your app or disables notifications for your app on their device, they are opted out of receiving messages that you create in MobilePush.


What would you say on an automation with "Import Mobile Contacts" which would take data from DE (used by a custom preference center) and add/update it in All Contacts? It would work the same way as the workaround with export, transfer, import to All Subscribers list.

@Dandys23 Yes. It would update the subscriber status but it doesn't serve the same purpose. Your subscribers go to the preference center since they want to opt in/opt out immediately while if you use an automation for this then it is a batch job

What about API call on the preference center (cloudpage)?

@Dandys23 If you mean the API call to update your Mobile Push subscriber status then it doesn't have any

There is an API call for update contact in the mobile push contact list - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_contacts/createContacts.html

If the user is turning off push notifications in the "preference center" then the SDKs, Android and iOS, will detect this during initialization and register the device with pushEnabled=false. That will opt the device out automatically in Contacts (and Marketing Cloud Push).

How? Since we use a custom preference center and we store the data in DE. SDK doesn't know anything about the preferences since the contact with mobile push data is not imported into All contacts.

This is not happening from an application with the push SDKs integrated in it?

There is a preference center on webpage, not in the mobile app. On the mobile the only way to opt out from pushes is by disable pushes for the app on an operating system level.
The case I'm interested in is how to integrate opt out on a preference center on webpage with opt out status in All Contacts in SFMC. Let's say I opt out / opt in on a preference center, and I'd like to have it reflected in All contacts.

So, yeah, that's an interesting issue. One clarification for anyone that finds this though, you can opt-out with the SDKs and that does not require anything in the OS (ref. https://bit.ly/4d4baMx). If you also have this contact tied to a mobile application with our SDKs then they're going to get opted back into push when the SDK sends the next registration. I don't think a server-side-only solution is going to work for you.
